# Xcode 10 Recent Project does not work correctly

Tags: xcode

i was updated my Xcode from 9.4 to 10
but now when i open it, there aren't any recent projects in lists. 
also when i open a project with Xcode 10, next time there isn't in list

[image: Xcode 10 recent projects problem]

Comment: Not a programming question. Try Ask Different.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is due to the system setting for recent items being set to `None`.

To fix:

- Navigate to System Preferences -> General -> Recent items
- Update Recent Items to any value, for example, `5`
- Relaunch Xcode

[image]

Comment: This may be right, but it is not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @matt it is related to IDE so we could consider it a development issue

Answer (score -2):

From System Preferences > General >**Uncheck** Close windows when quitting an application